# How does the surfaceview retain the color after glClear is called?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am just beginning to learn openGL and am working on android and am getting stuck in places. Please look at the code below:-

```
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {

    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {

    glClearColor(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
}
```

Here in onSurfaceCreated the color is set  and in onDrawFrame the color buffer is cleared. Now once the color buffer is cleared , why is the color of the surface still the same what was set in onSurfaceCreated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glClearColor` specifies the color that will be used to clear the buffer. When you call `glClear` this color will be applied to the buffer.

If you want a dark surface change it to:

```
 glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
```